# How to get access to CSS values from a styled component (React)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ref, styled-components

I want to access the CSS values I assigned to a styled component in a function. How would I do so?

For example:

```
const Hello = styled.p `
   font-size: 10px;
`;


getFontSize = () => {

}
```

I want to log the font size of the component Hello in the function getFontSize(). I have tried using refs and InnerRefs but no luck.

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `innerRef` prop on your component to get a reference to the DOM node, and then use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) on the node to get the `font-size`.

**Example**

```
const Hello = styled.input`
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  color: palevioletred;
  background: papayawhip;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
`;

class Form extends React.Component {
  ref = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFontSize();
  }

  getFontSize = () => {
    console.log(
      window.getComputedStyle(this.ref, null).getPropertyValue("font-size")
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <Hello innerRef={ref => (this.ref = ref)} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i get "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Comment: @Azimi Do you get that error from the example link in my answer? If you mean in your own code, you must make sure that the component has rendered first so that `ref` will be set.

Comment: yes my component is rendered, i am doing the call in the componentdidmount() function. Im doing it almost identical to how you did it.

Comment: @Azimi Alright. You might have missed some tiny detail. Are you assigning `ref` to `this.ref`, for example?

Comment: yes i am, <Text innerRef={ref => (this.ref = ref)}>

Comment: componentDidMount(){
        console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this.ref).getPropertyValue("font-size"))
    }

Comment: i figured out my issue, appreciate the help. Thanks again!

Comment: @Azimi Great! No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: is this the only way to do this by the way?

Comment: @Azimi It depends on the use case. You could have a regular JavaScript variable that you insert into the CSS and then just use the value of this variable directly instead.

Comment: Hey Tholle, is there a way to get the css values of a child in that component, for example. Say you want the css font-size of an <h1> component inside that ocmponent?

Comment: &: div {
 font-size: 10px
}


say there is a div inside of that component with css properties